# Make path that have same space between each other inner triangle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, cs6

I have created triangle, I want to create lines inner it. I successfully created some lines, but the space between other line is not same (sometimes further sometimes closer).

Lets look below image that I have created on Photoshop

[image: triangle]

That I want ask, How to create a collection of blue line (path) in above example with same space between each other? It's there tool in Illustrator to make 4 or 6 line with same space? thanks in advance

Comment: What if you form the big triangle from small triangle objects?

Comment: I think that's bad idea. Indirectly I must copied much of Triangle and arrange them position on by one.

Comment: It’s definitely a good idea. Using smart guides and ‘transform again’ you could assemble this from lots of little triangles in no time at all. Try that.

Comment: Draw one side and one set of cutting lines then rotate by 120 degrees. Is your aim a picxel graphic or a print graphic? (If its for screem you may consider deviating form 120 a bit so that the pixels go even in yoru design)

Comment: You had better to answer and explain your idea and how to do that. It'll be helpful for me. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the lines with a few Transform effects.

1. Draw a single horizontal line
2. Add a Transform effect (*Effect → Distort & Transform → Transform...*) with some vertical movement and a number of copies...

   [image]
3. Add a *second* Transform effect to the same line. Set the rotation angle to 60 degrees and the number of copies to 2...

   [image]
4. You can then go to *Object → Expand Appearance* to expand the lines (and use the Shape Builder tool or Pathfinder etc. if you want to construct shapes from the lines)

   [image]

Comment: but step 4 is not clear for me, I can expand the object and result much of path, how to remove the unused outside small triangle?

Comment: can you give me detail how to construct the object as you say?

Comment: @EngkusKusnadi using Shape Builder you just click+drag to create shapes or using Pathfinder's Divide will turn *all* the triangles in to their own shapes; it's then just a case of deleting the ones you don't need (I used the Lasso to select what I wanted to keep then inverted the selection and deleted)

Comment: See for example, with Shape Builder: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4gB2.gif ...or Pathfinder: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftua0.gif

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment, one way would be to Lego it up and use small triangles to form the big one.

You could make the gap with a stroke by aligning it inside so that you can easily snap them together. If you move the first triangle holding down `Alt`, you can repeat that with `Cmd+D`.

So basically:

1. Make the first triangle

   - I used red stroke to make aligning easier.
2. Copy / Move using mouse while holding down `Alt`
3. Repeat using `Object > Transform > Transform again` (`Cmd+D`)

   - Repeat until you got enough for the half of the bottom row
4. Group it `Cmd+G`
5. Copy `Cmd+C`
6. Paste in place `Cmd+F`
7. Rotate. I used Free transform tool `E`.
8. Align so that the saw teeth match.

   - You could do this by drawing a disposable rectangle. Size doesn't really matter as long as the right side is touching the vertical cernter of the right most triangle in the bottom half. Select that and the top half of the first row and use `Window > Align` with key object being the rectangle.
9. Copy / Move the whole bottom row using mouse while holding down `Alt`
10. Repeat using `Object > Transform > Transform again` (`Cmd+D`)

    - Repeat until you got enough to form the big triangle
11. Remove the extra triangles.

    - First I selected all of the triangles and then I used Shape builder tool `Shift+M` to unify the triangles I didn't need. Then I just selected them with the Selection Tool `V` and backspaced them out of my life.

[image]

Comment: @EngkusKusnadi, I added a gif of the process. It is like a minute long. There are browser extensions that let you pause and rewind gifs, like this one for Chrome: [GIF Scrubber](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gif-scrubber/gbdacbnhlfdlllckelpdkgeklfjfgcmp)

Comment: It's very difficult to snap on Step no. 8. I have turn on the Smart Guide, hold ctrl while dragging, but still not work.

Comment: @EngkusKusnadi I did appear to miss a step there, that is about aligning the top half of the bottom row. I suspect this is where you were stuck. I added a simple way to to align it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think a single tool can help you with this "Rectangular Grid Tool"

[image]

If you double click the icon, a popup will appear and you can enter the detail..

[image]