# Aligning key objects in a diagonal fashion?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, spacing

I am trying to align honeycomb evenly in AI. Attached is a photo but I am trying to change the graphic slightly to create a divider on a menu I am designing. So, the current one I have is too large, and I am not sure if the spacing on it is even correct. Help! Attached are ss of both. The first one is what I am trying to evenly space out, and the second one is already evenly spaced. I could eye it as I usually do, but it is so time consuming! Thanks for your help!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To properly align everything I would follow the guide from [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/110751/63979).

Then to create the spacing, just expand everything end **Right click → Transform → Transform Each** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

And scale them down 80-90% (make sure both are equal).

[image: scaled down 85%]

<sup>▲ This is 85%</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Or just use stoke on all hexagons. Use the “Align Stroke to Inside” button in the stroke palette. Expand objects when done. Or create a pattern.

[image]

**Pro tip:** to quickly align polygons, use <kbd>v</kbd> to grab anchor, **not** edge, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> to duplicate, then also hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while dragging. This will trigger the old snap behavior (less pink distribute guides shown) and will let you slide along edges or precisely at anchors. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to repeat last operation (duplicate + move). Select row/column/diagonal of polys and repeat …